# What's the difference when using m,a here?

Tags: python

```
class Enemy:
 name = ""
 lives = 0
 def __init__(self, name, lives):
   self.name = name
   self.lives = lives

def hit(self):
  self.lives -= 1
 if self.lives <= 0:
    print(self.name + ' killed')
 else:
     print(self.name + ' has '+ str(self.lives) + ' lives')

class Monster(Enemy):
def __init__(self):
 super().__init__('Monster', 3)

class Alien(Enemy):
 def __init__(self):
     super().__init__('Alien', 5)

（wrong code)while True:
 x = input()
 if x == 'exit':
     break
 if x=='gun':
      Monster().hit()
 if x=='laser':
      Alien().hit()
(correct code)
 m = Monster()
 a = Alien()
while True:
 x = input()
 if x == 'exit':
     break
 if x=='gun':
     m.hit()
 if x=='laser':
     a.hit()
```

I‘m a python beginner,As I see this, the two codes are the same.
but the wrong code:input: laser
laser
laser
output:Alien has 4 lives
Alien has 4 lives
Alien has 4 lives
but the right output is:Alien has 4 lives
Alien has 3 lives
Alien has 2 lives

Comment: Please fix the code indentation. Preferably using 4 spaces for each indentation level.

Comment: Each time you call `Monster()` it creates a new monster, and it starts out with 3 lives. You need to create a single monster so that the lives will keep decreasing instead of starting over.

Comment: TLDR: you can not chain python constructors (`__init__`). They return `None`, unlike their corresponding constructors in other languages like `cpp`. Just assign `m = Monster(...)` then use the instance `m` to do whatever you like.

Comment: @OrenIshShalom what? What do you mean "chain constructors". For starters, `__init__` is not a constructor, it is an initializer. But in any case, what does that have to do with the behavior here?

Comment: In short - in the first, you create new objects on each iteration, in the second, you re-use the same objects

Comment: The OP wants to do `Monster().some_method()` which is not possible since `__init__` returns `None`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit rusty with Python, but I will try to map out what is happening in the two variations of your code.  First off, Python like C++, allows for the use of an entity called a class.  A class usually is thought of as a template from which objects can be created (as in your case one or more Monsters and one or more Aliens).  The usual way to do that is how you defined variables (objects) "m" and "a".

```
m = Monster()
a = Alien()
```

Object "m" then is entitled to utilize all functions defined in the "Monster" class as well as inherited functions from the "Enemy" class.  The same holds true with the "a" object and the "Alien" and "Enemy" class.  That way, in a game there could be multiple monsters and aliens as in the following example.

```
m1 = Monster()
m2 = Monster()
m3 = Monster()
a1 = Alien()
a2 = Alien()
a3 = Alien()
```

In the code variation where you directly called the "hit" function for the class, what you ultimately did was create a temporary object for the "Alien" and then executed the "hit" function.  So, in effect, every time you execute the "Alien().hit" function, your program was initiating a new "Alien" with five lives, decrementing the lives and printing out the result of four lives.  Honestly, I don't recall if that "Alien" sticks around in memory or disappears when you again call the  "hit" function.

To best illustrate that behavior, I added in a print command within the class initialization definition for the "Monster" and "Alien" class.

```
class Monster(Enemy):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('Monster', 3)
        print("Monster has been created")

class Alien(Enemy):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('Alien', 5)
        print("Alien has been created")
```

I then used the code you noted as incorrect and ran the program.  Following is the printed output I received.

```
laser
Alien has been created
Alien has 4 lives
laser
Alien has been created
Alien has 4 lives
laser
Alien has been created
Alien has 4 lives
exit
```

I then used the code where you properly create objects for the monster and alien (objects "m" and "a") and then executed the same laser selection.

```
Monster has been created
Alien has been created
laser
Alien has 4 lives
laser
Alien has 3 lives
laser
Alien has 2 lives
laser
Alien has 1 lives
laser
Alien killed
exit
```

So when you create an object from a class and then execute a function associated with the object, you should get the behavior you desire.  When you utilize a class function directly, you probably will get unpredictable results at best.

Hope that clarifies things.

Regards.

Comment: "Honestly, I don't recall if that "Alien" sticks around in memory or disappears when you again call the "hit" function." Since no reference exists for those objects, after the method call terminates, the objects are set for garbage collection. In CPython, the main garbage collection strategy is reference counting, and the objects are immediately reclaimed when their reference count reaches 0

Comment: " When you utilize a class function directly, you probably will get unpredictable results at best." the wording here is misleading, in neither case is the class function being used directly - both are being used on an instance, which is the typical way. And the behavior is completely predicatable

Comment: Thanks for the additional information in your comments.  As I noted, I am a bit rusty with Python.